# Image zooms and fades on rollover, to reveal text below

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to get this effect to work as I want, but have spent hours on it without success.

Basically, what I am looking for is a div that contains an image.
When the mouse pointer hovers over the image, it zooms in and fades out to show a blue background and a text description below.

I've sorted the zooming effect, I've sorted the fading effect, I've got the text positioned within the div as I want it, but I just can't get it to go underneath the image in its initial state.

I've tried z-index values and opacities, but the text always appears on top of the image.

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Please find my html and css below:

```
<div class="randomItem">
<div class="hidden_text">
Vintage Projects
<br>
Click to find out more
</div>
<a href="vintage.html">
<img src="img/vintage/rizla3.jpg" alt="Vintage Projects" class="randomImage">
</a>
</div>
```

```
.hidden_text        {color: white;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    position:absolute;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;
                    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                    text-align: center;
                    cursor: pointer;}

.randomItem         {border:3px solid #ddd;
                    position:relative;
                    display:inline-block;
                    margin:0.79%;
                    overflow:hidden;
                    width:31%;
                    -webkit-transition:all .3s;
                    -o-transition:all .3s;
                    transition:all .3s;
                    background:#009fdf;}
                    
.randomImage        {display:block;
                    height:auto;
                    max-width:100%;
                    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
                    -o-transition:all .5s;
                    transition:all .5s;
                    opacity:1;}
                    
.randomImage:hover{-webkit-transform: scale(1.3);-ms-transform: scale(1.3);transform: scale(1.3); opacity:0;}

.randomItem:hover   {border-color: #009fdf;}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: You said you tried opacity, but setting opacity to zero in.hidden_text doesn't hide the text? At least, it should like here: https://jsfiddle.net/4oxqw0uf/

Comment: Hello Simone

Thanks for the reply.

Yes, setting hidden_text to opacity:0 hides the text in the initial state, but I'm unsure how to get it to show on rollover, as creating a hover state and setting opacity:1 doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I've understood your question better, I'll answer you. From the comments, the opacity for hover doesn't work since the element is not in sight, so you can't hover on it. You need to hover on another element, like the parent, always visible. Like in the following statements (same fiddle as before https://jsfiddle.net/4oxqw0uf/2/):

```
/*initial disappear*/
.hidden_text {
    ...
    opacity:0;
}
/*Making appear again on hover*/
.randomItem:hover .hidden_text {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!

That now works exactly as I want it.

Thanks very much for your help

Comment: Glad it works! If you like, you may accept the answer thus closing the question.

Comment: @neilwhitedesign have you considered accepting the answer? Please, take a [tour] to understand how this pages work.